# Bar chart in R with 2 bars for each item

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want bar chart with ggplot2 (in R). I would like to have 2 bars for each month.

```
monthyear = c('January 2015', 'February 2015', 'March 2016', 
             'April 2016', 'May 2016', 'June 2016', 'July 2016', 
             'January 2017', 'Februrary 2017', 
             'August 2017', 'September 2017', 'October 2017')

c_report = c(742, 3420, 4263, 5147, 6255, 93872, 2323, 
             4677, 9398, 2112, 1000, 7890)

o_report = c(30185, 33894, 33642, 29439, 27879 ,52347, 
              4578, 3639, 10000, 48781, 64484, 5020)

df = data.frame(monthyear, c_report, o_report)

ggplot(data = df , aes(x=c_report, y = o_report, fill = monthyear) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Below is the graph of the above code.

[image]

**But I am expecting the graph to be something like shown below.**

[image]

Comment: `geom_col()` is now recommended in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the data to draw a grouped bar chart.

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data.m <- melt(df, id.vars='dateyear')

ggplot(data.m, aes(dateyear, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```